# NGINX + Php-Fpm - No input file specified

Tags: php, yii2, nginx, php-fpm

не могу запустить сайт на локалке. изобрадения видит, а php-файлы не хочет обрабатывать. 2 часа попаюсь, не могу разобраться.

```
server {

    server_name yaposad.localhost;
    listen 80;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/yaposad-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/yaposad-error.log;

    # root /srv/www/yaposad/web;
    root /home/zaars/Projects/Yii2/yaposad/web;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
            root /home/zaars/Projects/Yii2/yaposad/web;
            index index.php index.html;
    #   try_files $uri $uri/ = 404;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {

            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            try_files $uri =404;

            include fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

fastcgi_params (тоже что и в fastcgi.conf)

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING   $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE   $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI   $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Comment: unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock; Тут не забыли /var, случайно?

Comment: @ilyaplot нет. сокет там и находится. больше скажу: даже через порт происходит тоже самое

Comment: а что в fastcgi_params и fastcgi_conf находится?

Comment: там ничего не менял, все по умолчанию

Comment: У меня схожая проблема, решили ситуацию ?

Comment: не помню как решил